# Ben Kamtza and Bar Kamtza

Tags: historical-figures

In the Y.K. Davening, we read about kohanim who kept trade secrets of the temple to themselves. One of these, Ben Kamtza, knew a way of writing gods name with four pens in one hand so all the letters complete at once.

I think the spelling is the same than Bar Kamtsa linked to Chorban but can't check now.

Are there any mephorshim that link the two personalities/families?

Comment: Which two? You mention one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Mishna Yoma the spelling is Ben Kamtsa**R** "בן קמצ**ר**" with a "Resh". See the different versions in this [edition's up right margin](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37942&st=&pgnum=31&hilite=).
Soncino's Translation in Gemara Yoma 38a:

> Ben kamzar would not teach anyone his art of writing.

We find Kamtza in Gemara Gittin 55b:

> אמר רבי יוחנן מאי דכתיב (משלי כח) אשרי אדם מפחד תמיד ומקשה לבו יפול  ברעה אקמצא ובר קמצא חרוב ירושלים
>
> R'Johanan said: What is illustrative of the verse, Happy is the man that feareth alway, but he that hardeneth his heart shall fall into mischief? The destruction of Jerusalem came through a Kamza and a Bar Kamza.

Comment: Isn't it fitting that someone who doesn't teach the art  of writing has his name written wrong?